# Suggestion regarding MySql ID column - Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

In Rails app, instead of creating default Mysql/Postgres ID columns as Integers, which is very easy to guess the next number while hitting the routes, what is the best way to generate the ID column ( AlphaNumeric may be?) which is going to very hard to guess.

> I did some research on creating UUID's, is this a good option? or, are
>   there any other options?
>
> How about generating EPOCH timestamps and storing them as ID's on
>   before_save callback each time ?

Comment: Generally you do not want to expose internal database ids to the end user. What is the actual requirement? Is it to prevent access to a resource? If so, what grants access and what denies access?

Comment: This is just security by obscurity - any system that relies on masking keys is an insecure system.

Answer (score 0):

Usings UUID's to cover the database IDs is an example of security by obscurity.

> "System security should not depend on the secrecy of the
> implementation or its components."
>
> - National Institute of Standards and Technology

Consider the cases where an attacker could actually use his knowledge of a primary key to attack a system - SQL injection (you're screwed anyways), and brute force attacks. You should have better guards in place.

That being said there are valid use cases for using UUID's - the main one being that distributed databases using sequential auto increment columns are prone to race conditions.

If you have several "write" replications than extensive steps have to be taken to make sure the ID's are in sync and problems can occur if records are inserted simultaneously in different databases.

When generating a unique ID a hashing algorithm with a low chance of collision should be used. Currently the SHA-1 algorithm is recommended by the [RFC4122](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122). Earlier standards used a scheme where the generating computer MAC address was combined with a timestamp but this was not deemed opaque enough [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Variants_and_versions).

MongoDB uses 8 bit object ID identifiers by default - this ties in with the fact that it is built to replicate.
[MongoDB uses the following to construct its object IDs](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/):

- a 4-byte value representing the seconds since the Unix epoch,
- a 3-byte machine identifier,
- a 2-byte process id, and
- a 3-byte counter, starting with a random value.

Note that these are generated by the database - not the web server utilising the database.

There are also [several esoteric algorithms](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/49550/which-hashing-algorithm-is-best-for-uniqueness-and-speed) designed to have a high uniqueness without the cost of a designated password hashing algorithm such as [Blowfish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blowfish_(cipher)).

### Conclusion:

Use UUID's if you can foresee that you will have a scaling problem that requires database duplication.

Whatever algorithm you use will probably be strong enough to avoid [pigeonhole problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) - but you should not really roll your own - this problem has been extensively researched and there are solutions with many man hours behind them available for free.

The security gains are marginal at best.

Comment: And if you're really concerned about security - don't use MySQL. It has a lackadaisical adherence to the SQL standards and a weird quoting scheme.

Comment: Add your comment to your answer.